# Transparent Database Cache

Tags: database, oracle, caching

I have an application that calls a third party product. This product makes a large number of database calls as part of its processing, although the data in the database is generally static (unless the data is updated maybe once per day by a refresh mechanism).
As the data is very static, but the database is under a heavy load, I want to put a caching layer inbetween the application and the database. As the application is a third party product (written in C), I can't implement the cache in code myself. So...

is there a product, or tool that can transparently sit in between the application and the database that can act as a cache. Something that can intercept the requests, respond with cached data if it has it, or send it down to the database if it does not.

I know that databases have their caches, but I am looking to offload the workload to the application's server rather than the ratabase server to reduce the workload going on the DB server (which has significant licence costs).

Comment: Oracle TimesTen might fit the bill http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/timesten/overview/index.html